# How to add and submit input fields using a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, forms

How can I add and submit the post without user login? By that I mean an offline user can add some content on WordPress and submit it, like simple forms in PHP.

I tried this code:

```
public function add_shortcode_fileds() {
    add_shortcode( 'add_fields', 'input_fields' );
    function input_fields( $atts ) {
        $atts='<form method="post" action="">';
        $atts.='<input type="text">';
        $atts.='<input type="submit">';
        $atts.='</form';
        return $atts;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by offline user?

Comment: yes my mean is that https://plugin-planet.com/usp-pro/ user submitted post plugin i don't want to give access to user to login on WordPress and add his post i want he add his post from front end i handle this code using short code do you have any idea ??

Comment: i want insert my post using shortcode i dont used any other person plugin i make my own plugin

Comment: so its the simple process, what you have tried so far and having difficulty?

Comment: public function add_shortcode_fileds(){
   add_shortcode('add_fields','input_fields');
    function input_fields($atts){
     $atts='<form method="post" action="">';
     $atts.='<input type="text">';
     $atts.='<input type="submit">';
     $atts.='</form';
     return $atts;
    }
  }

Comment: i added the code in post and comment also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the shortcode like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'add_fields', 'input_fields' ); 
function input_fields( $atts ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['gg'] ) ) {
        $post = array(
            'post_content' => $_POST['content'], 
            'post_title'   => $_POST['title']
        );
        $id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
    }
    ?> 
    <form method = "post">
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="text" name="content">
        <input type="submit" name="gg">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

It's just a sample usage, you can check in detail [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: sorry one more thing how i add this post in my custom post type :)

Comment: Yes, you can add post_category in query array :)